# Applying steps to validation data as well or only to training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have an image classification problem and I want to use the pretrained model EfficicentNetB0 (keras applications: https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function and the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946) with weights from ImageNet for this classification problem.

I downloaded and imported the model and its weights as follows:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
import efficientnet.keras as efn
efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False
```

I won't include the top of this model because it does not fit the problem I am analyzing, that is why I set `include_top` to `False`. Moreover, I don't want to train the parameters of the EfficientNet, therefore `efnB0_model.trainable = False`.

Now, I would like to apply the `efnB0_model` to the training data `X_train`  one time (it is not necessary to do this more than once because the weights are already there and should not be changed) and freeze all this bottom layers afterwards.

Therefore, I created a `DataGenerator_X`.

```
class DataGenerator_X(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, batch_size):
        self.x = x_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = [imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        

        return batch_x
```

This `DataGenerator_X` creates batches and divides them by 255 (that is preferred by EfficicentNet).

After that I apply this `DataGenerator_X` to `X_train` (which is the file_path to my images).

```
training_generator = DataGenerator_X(X_train, batch_size=32)
```

And then I predict the `X_train` values after running the bottom of the EfficientNet-B0 model on them (`X_after_efn`) in order to not have to do this every epoch again because the bottom layers of the model are all freezed. I do that by using this code:

```
X_after_efn_train = efnB0_model.predict(training_generator, verbose=1)
```

What I am wondering is, if I have to apply all this steps to the validation data as well? So, do I also have to create `validation_generator` and `X_after_efn_val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. You'll have to create a `validation_generator` and then run `efnB0_model.predict()` on it.

The main reason for this is the `predict()` function only takes a single set of input samples (check input `x` under `predict` method https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#predict-method).

On the bright side, it's not too much work since you can use the same generator.

```
val_generator = DataGenerator_X(X_val, batch_size=32)
X_after_efn_val = efnB0_model.predict(val_generator, verbose=1)
```

You can also check the 'using bottleneck features' part of this blog. They do something similar. https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Thank you! And my data generator will not change the order of the X-values, correct? So I don't have to sort them by any attribute after the generation if the order was correct before?